# Create custom 'Add to cart' with wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I fetch a specific product in a page that is outside of woocommerce template and I need to add the 'Add to cart' button. I looked at the code and I saw woocommerce doing it this way,

```
<a href="/?product_cat=icecream&amp;add-to-cart=77" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="77" data-product_sku="" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>
```

I tried to change the product_id and everything to be fit to my needs like this,

```
<a href="/?product_cat=icecream&amp;add-to-cart=<?php echo $id; ?>" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-product_sku="" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">
    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/add_to_cart.png" alt="Add to cart" />
</a>
```

but it dosen't get saved for some reason (when I get into cart page its empty). I'm trying also to lose the "View Cart" button that gets near when the item is added, if someone can guide me how can I create that button and where to shall I redirect it, it would be perfect (:

thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can do it with ajax, you can redirect it to - '?add-to-cart=' and the item will get into the cart. so you will be able to design you'r button however you want ..

Comment: Any possibilities of including a quantity? Like '/?add-to-cart=1001&quantity=2/' ?

Answer (score 7):

It only works in shop page this way. Try this for other pages:

```
$product = get_product(77);
echo "<a href='" . $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>add to cart</a>";
```

Comment: As I said its not on the shop page.

Comment: What i meant to say is you code will work only in shop page. This one will work in other pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the add to cart shortcode.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart id=' . $id . ']' ) ?>
```

Assuming you already have $id.

Comment: How do you define `$id` to pull the id of the product?

Comment: @Darren - You have to enter the ID yourself. WooCommerce has to know which product you intent to show, assuming you're adding this on a custom page and not the product page.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcode already gives you the AJAX functionality.

Try this:

```
<?php
global $product;
$pid = $product->get_id();
?>
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart_url id=' . $pid . ']' ) ?>" class="your-classes-here">Add to cart</a>
```

You'll find more info here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Hope you'd find this useful.